# How can I set the value of a List box using jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

Hi I have a List which is returned by a webmethod. This needs to be set to a Listbox ? How can this be done ? Thanks in advance

I set the value of 2 labels using this code . Now need to set a listbox as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetTime1",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            $('#<%=Label2.ClientID %>').html(result.d.Label1);
            $('#<%=Label3.ClientID %>').html(result.d.Label2);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the object of this class returned by the webmethod

```
public class StatusViewModel
    {
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string Label2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> ListBox { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, ListBox are already at the page, let it have server id lbYourListBox

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.ListBox.length; i++) {  
  $(document.createElement("option")).attr("value",result.ListBox[i]).html(result.ListBox[i])
   .appendTo('#<%=lbYourListBox.ClientID  %>')}
```

Comment: Thanks..Works just fine.. Just needed to add 'd' in result.d.ListBox[i]

Answer (score 1):

Try to return a list and then bind your list to your listbox.

```
 $.each(ListBox, function(index, item) {
                                $("#ListBoxtoBeFilled").get(0).options[$("#ListBoxtoBeFilled").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item);
                             });
```